# Join all keys from object that contain same number and returns array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, javascript-objects

I'm attempting to join all keys/values that have the same number. So for example, if the key name is `alfa0: 'theValueOfAlfa'` and there is another key with the same number (in this case 0) `beta0: 'theValueOfBeta'`, I would like to join them and return a object:

```
{
  name: 'theValueOfAlfa',
  value: 'theValueOfBeta'
}
```

This object:

```
const vls = {"lote0": "jg", "lote1": "h", "lote2": "fm", "loteQnt0": "jgvalue", "loteQnt1": "hvalue", "loteQnt2": "fmvalue" }
```

the expected output:

```
const result = [
 {
   name: 'jg',
   value: 'jgvalue'
 },
 ...
]
```

Comment: Your "array" looks an awful lot like an object. In JavaScript, arrays are denoted by `[ ]`, objects by `{ }`. Entries of arrays are denoted by commas only, whereas keys and values are separated by colons, each pair separated by a comma.

Comment: Yep, I misspelled it

Comment: It would be good if you tried something, or showed where your research got you to. For instance, some cursory searching found [Convert key value pair to array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70348265/215552), which is quite close...

Comment: Are keys without character prefix allowed? For example: "1"

Comment: not, there will always be `lote{someNumber}` and `loteQnd{someNumber}` @Lesiak

Comment: @Lesiak I think that is close, I have posted a answer with my code, have a look

Answer (score 0):

I create this snippet which can deal with the case. I don't believe this is the best approach, but it is a solution

```
const v = {"lote0": "jg", "lote1": "h", "lote2": "fm", "loteQnt0": "jgvalue", "loteQnt1": "hvalue", "loteQnt2": "fmvalue" }

const lote = Object.keys(v).filter((k, v) => {
    return k.match(/lote\d+$/);
}).reduce((obj, key) => {
        obj[key] = v[key];
        return obj;
  }, {});

const loteQnt = Object.keys(v).filter((k, v) => {
    return k.indexOf('loteQnt') == 0;
}).reduce((obj, key) => {
        obj[key] = v[key];
        return obj;
  }, {});

const arr = []

Object.entries(lote).forEach((k, i) => {
    console.log(k[1])
    const obj = {}
    obj['lote'] = k[1]
    obj['loteQnt'] = Object.values(loteQnt)[i]    
    arr.push(obj)

})

result:
[LOG]: [{
  "lote": "jg",
  "loteQnt": "jgvalue"
}, {
  "lote": "h",
  "loteQnt": "hvalue"
}, {
  "lote": "fm",
  "loteQnt": "fmvalue"
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve this by iterating over an object to get the keys in an array and then fetch the numbers using `RegEx` and then perform the assignment into a new object.

Live Demo **:**

```js
function groupValuesByNumber(obj) {
  const groupedValues = {};

  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    const match = key.match(/\d+$/);
    if (match) {
      const number = match[0];
      !groupedValues[number] ?
        groupedValues[number] = { name: obj[key] } : groupedValues[number].value = obj[key]
    }
  })

  // Convert the groupedValues object to an array of objects
  const result = Object.values(groupedValues);

  return result;
}

const obj = {
  "lote0": "jg",
  "lote1": "h",
  "lote2": "fm",
  "loteQnt0": "jgvalue",
  "loteQnt1": "hvalue",
  "loteQnt2": "fmvalue"
};

const result = groupValuesByNumber(obj);

console.log(result);
```